# Divide and Conquer division algorithm explained (as used in GMP bignum)

Tags: optimization, algorithms, computer-arithmetic

I am trying to understand the divide and conquer division algorithm that [is used in the GMP bignum arithmetic library](https://gmplib.org/manual/Divide-and-Conquer-Division.html).

The code is very optimised and that makes it somewhat hard to understand. the doc does not really offer an explanation of how it is done, (and the references do not point to an actual algorithm, not one that I could see anyway).

I understand the concept of divide and conquer for sorting, but I am not sure I understand how it can be used in a division.

How can $x \over y$ be calculated using divide and conquer?

Can someone give a small example of how it is done?

Comment: What about this reference? http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.47.565&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Thanks I will have a proper look now, but I cannot see the divide and conquer method.

Comment: In this context, "recursive algorithm" = "divide and conquer algorithm".

Comment: got it, thanks. Still a bit murky and heavy reading, but I will try and come up with an example.